# Does UserProfile.BatchUpdate.API updates the OOTB property as well?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-property, userprofiles, aad

I want to sync the Mobile Phone property from AAD to SharePoint User Profile for all the users on a regular basis.

As mentioned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/user-profile-sync#properties-that-are-synced-into-sharepoint-user-profiles), the Mobile Phone property is not getting synced in OOTB sync process.

I came across [Bulk update custom user profile properties for SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/bulk-user-profile-update-api-for-sharepoint-online) which mentioned that it is used to bulk update **CUSTOM** properties.

Can I use the same for OOTB property as well?

As, it's a long procedure to do the feasibility check, It will be really helpful to get a heads up to see if someone has tried this earlier.